# JSON in SQL - Best way to get all nested keys

Tags: sql, json, ssms

I'm working with JSON in MS SQL and trying to figure out what the best way to get all the key/value pairs? I pulled a row in Azure Data Studio and it formats the data for me to better view, but is there a better way or sql code that will show all the key/value pairs for me?

The examples that I am finding online is showing code similar to below, which pulls back the values, but if I have 20+ keys, is there a better way than to type each one in? Also, what happens if an extra set of data gets added down the line without my knowledge? Wouldn't it help to be able to loop through these key items? Any suggestions on how to pull all this information for SSMS?

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(f.doc, '$.id')  AS Name, 
   JSON_VALUE(f.doc, '$.address.city') AS City,
   JSON_VALUE(f.doc, '$.address.county') AS County
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, so I'll comment rather than answer. 
 A generalised way to translate a `JSON` object in to a row/set is described in MS's online docs here : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15  As for adding new columns for new keys; no.  SQL Is effectively a statically typed language and the column names, data-types, etc, can't be dynamic.  The solution to that style of problem is either code-which-writes-sql or to fix your data structure (new rows, not new columns).

Answer (score 0):

Note: Static SQL ***can not*** have dynamic numbers of columns depending on the data.

Either...

- Normalise the data, such that you're adding rows not columns *(as per this answer)*
- Work with a fixed number of columns only
- Use DynamicSQL (Code that reads the data, writes not SQL, then executes the new SQL)

---

To be truly generic, and accommodate any number of keys, you could recursively open the json and create a new ***ROW*** for each key...

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  row_id  INT,
  json    NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO
  example
VALUES
  (1, N'{"id": 1, "address": {"city": "city_1", "county": "county_1"}}'),
  (2, N'{"id": 2, "address": {"city": "city_2", "county": "county_2", "nation": "uk"}}'),
  (3, N'{"id": 3, "an_array": [{"city": "city_3"},999,"smeg"]}')
```

Code:

```
WITH
  recursed_open_json AS
(
  SELECT
    example.row_id,
    open_json.*
  FROM
    example
  CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(json) AS open_json

  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    r.row_id,
    CASE WHEN r.type = 4
         THEN r.[key] + '[' + o.[key] + ']'
         ELSE r.[key] + '.' + o.[key]       END,
    o.value,
    o.type
  FROM
    recursed_open_json   AS r
  CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(r.value) AS o
  WHERE
    r.type IN (4, 5)
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  recursed_open_json
WHERE
  type NOT IN (4, 5)
ORDER BY
  row_id,
  [key]
```

Results:

| row_id | key | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | address.city | city_1 | 1 |
| 1 | address.county | county_1 | 1 |
| 1 | id | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | address.city | city_2 | 1 |
| 2 | address.county | county_2 | 1 |
| 2 | address.nation | uk | 1 |
| 2 | id | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | an_array[0].city | city_3 | 1 |
| 3 | an_array[1] | 999 | 2 |
| 3 | an_array[2] | smeg | 1 |
| 3 | id | 3 | 2 |